# GitHub not working on Linux unless VPN is used, but working totally fine with Windows

Tags: networking, wireless, vpn, webserver, github

I've been trying to learn coding and the course uses Linux (Ubuntu). I've run Xubuntu on VM and Ubuntu on dual-boot with Windows 11, but the GitHub website isn't working on either of them except with VPN (Browsec for Chrome). However, it works perfectly fine on my Windows, as well as my Android phone.

My internet connection is from my university, and it needs a username and a password, the authentication type being used on Windows is PEAP and I used the same on Ubuntu dual boot.

GitHub is apparently needed throughout the course so I really need to resolve this issue ASAP.

By "not working", I mean the website doesn't load when I open it on the browser, and on Firefox I get the error "Server not found" and Chrome tells me " DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It is not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you suggest an appropriate site for asking this question?

Comment: It is a network problem. Maybe your university doesn't allow two connections, etc.